Goodstein sequence monotonicity
Does Goodstein's sequence oscillate after it reaches its maximum or does it decrease monotonously from its maximum value to zero?
Wikipedia describes some results about the rate of growth when the function increases, not on the side where it decreases though.
An informal definition of Goodstein's sequence
----------------------------------------------
G(0) = n expressed in hereditary base-2 notation. //meaning base=2 whose exponents' base=2 ... whose exponents' base=2 and so on.
For each k ≥ 0, express G(k) in hereditary base-k+2 notation. 
Replace all bases (k+2) with (k+3) in this expression.
Subtract 1 from the resulting number to get G(k+1).
Continue until reaching 0. //Goodstein's theorem

It would be useful for future visitors, to link a study of the monotonicity; particularly at the decreasing side of G.

So that the question doesn't get further down-voted here is a quick study I did for the weak Goodstein sequence:
At one iteration f(b) the sequence is
$a_0+...+a_Nb^N$

$\forall a_i=0$ $a_0+...+a_Nb^N-1=a_0-1$ it decreases
$\\ $

Else let $m$ be the first index such that $a_m\neq0$


$a_0+\dots+a_Nb^N-1= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{m-1}(b-1)b^k+(a_m-1)b^m+\Big( a_{m+1}b^{m+1}+\dots+a_Nb^N \Big) $
The next iteration increases the base by one:
$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m-1}(b-1)(b+1)^k+(a_m-1)(b+1)^m+\Big( a_{m+1}(b+1)^{m+1}+\dots+a_N(b+1)^N \Big)$
$ (x+y)^n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^{n-k} y^k$
The difference between consecutive iterations (f(b+1)-f(b)) equals:
$ \sum\limits_{k=0}^{m-1}(b-1)(b+1)^k -1 (b+1)^m+ \Big(  a_m\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m-1} \binom{m}{k} b^{k}+\dots+a_N\sum\limits_{k=0}^{N-1} \binom{N}{k} b^{k} \Big)=$
$$ \sum\limits_{k=0}^{m-1}\Big\{ (b-1)(b+1)^k\Big\}-b^m+ \Big(  (a_m-1)\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m-1} \binom{m}{k} b^{k}+\dots+a_N\sum\limits_{k=0}^{N-1} \binom{N}{k} b^{k} \Big)>0$$ I think, so probably it does oscillate. Correct me if I'm wrong, I wrote this in a hurry.
Below is a drawing I got from rising-entropy.

